# Error while building docker image using jib

Tags: docker, jhipster, jib, maven-jib

I am using `mvnw -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild` to build the docker image for my jHipster project and I am getting:
***Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:3.2.1:dockerBuild (default-cli)Build to Docker daemon failed, perhaps you should make sure your credentials for 'registry-1.docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin' are set up correctly. See https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-should-i-do-when-the-registry-responds-with-unauthorized for help: Unauthorized for registry-1.docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin: 401 Unauthorized
[ERROR] {"details":"incorrect username or password"}***
What actually need the authorization? Is it for pulling the eclipse-temurin? or is it pushing something to registry-1.docker.io?

Comment: It is a common misunderstanding that public images on Docker Hub (`temurin` in this case) don't requires authentication. You do need to authenticate. It is just that you can skip sending a username and a password for public images. Apparently, Jib was able to pick up some credentials on your machine and sent them to Docker Hub. Then, Docker Hub reports that the username and password given to the server are wrong (e.g., typo). Check the Jib log to figure out where it was able to pick up the username and password. Removing them will make it work.

Comment: actually after giving the authentication like **docker login https://registry-1.docker.io** it worked. Sorry I am new to docker and not sure whether this registry-1.docker.io is a mirror hub or something. My credentials were correct only

Comment: `registry-1.docker.io` is Docker Hub. Simply doing `docker login` would have the same effect as `docker login registry-1.docker.io`. Anyways, since you logged in successfully, now it should work fine.

Comment: simply giving docker login didn't work in my case, after I logged in using **docker login registry-1.docker.io** only I was able to build. I could see 2 different entries in ~/.docker/config.json file

Comment: I ran docker logout, removed the config.json and also signed out of Docker Desktop.
Then did the login with Docker Destop and it started to work.
Oddly config.json was not recreated so Docker Desktop probably put the secrets into macosxkeychain.

Comment: @Abin you saved my day. docker login didn't fix my issue, but passing the registry-1 did fix it for jib plugin. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Approach that worked for me: 
Using your cmd/terminal logout from docker using `docker logout` command. 
Next login to docker from cmd/terminal using `docker login`  command. 
You will be prompted to enter your username and password (one you used for creating your dockerhub account). 
After successful login try executing the command `mvn compile jib: dockerBuild`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. docker logout
2. docker login -u myusername -p mypassword
3. mvn compile jib:dockerBuild